# Is this the correct way of solve a probability question from a deck of cards?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, sampling-theory

You draw a card from a standard deck of $52$ playing cards then replace it in the deck and draw a second card. Determine the probability of drawing an eight and then heart

[image: click here to see the decks of card image]

My work:

their are $4$ eights and $13$ hearts

So the deck is out of $52$ cards, so you multiply $4/52\times13/52= 1/52$.

The answer is $1/52$.

Is this the correct way of solve thing question?

Comment: Yes, this is correct for the problem where we replaced the card inbetween draws.  Now, the next question you are probably going to be asked is what happens if we *didn't* replace the card between each.

Comment: well it would be a dependent event, because its going to have an affect  on the outcome, so the deck would be out of a different number due to no replacement depending on which card its asking for @JMoravitz

Comment: You'd think that, wouldn't you?  However... it is best to approach by raw mathematical definitions here... not by imprecise "intuitive descriptions."

Comment: Considering the problem without replacement... So, first card is an 8 and second card is a heart., that can be broken down to first card is an 8 of hearts and second card is another heart *or* first card is an 8 non-heart and second card is a heart.  You have then a probability of $\frac{1}{52}\times\frac{12}{51} + \frac{3}{52}\times\frac{13}{51} = \frac{1}{52}$... perhaps surprisingly the same probability as what we had before.  The point to take away from this second problem is that events which our intuition says should be dependent *still might not be*...

Comment: ... that "drawing an 8 on the first card" is in fact independent of "drawing a heart on the second card" *regardless* of whether or not we drew with or without replacement (*though this is admittedly not easy to see without having actually run the numbers*).

Answer (score 4):

You are correct! For any two **independent** events A and B:

$$P(\text{A and B}) = P(A)P(B)$$

Because you put the card back in between, the events have no relation to each other - which card you draw the first time has no bearing on which one you draw the second time. Thus, they are independent, and you can calculate the probability in this way.

If you would like to know more, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)).